# My friend booked hostel by his name for us (2 beds). Can I use that document for a Schengen visa application?

Tags: visas, schengen, hostels, hostelworld

I am applying for a Schengen visa through hostelworld. In hostelworld booking confirmation it starts with

> Hi (Name of the person who did the booking).

I booked a few hostels with 2 beds for a friend traveling with me and he booked a few hostels. In the ones that he booked his name appears in the booking with 2 beds but not my name.

Can this be a problem for a Schengen visa application? Should he cancel his booking and let me book them instead?

He is not travelling with me, I will meet him there.

Comment: Common sense would indicate that if you’re not travelling together and you are applying for a visa, then the booking should be in your name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expected to include evidence of accommodations for your entire trip, so the easiest resolution would be for your friend to have your name added to the reservations.

If that is not possible, you might follow the guidance in its VFS Global [checklist](http://www.vfsglobal.com/italy/australia/pdf/Vfs_cheklist_210616.pdf) (although Italy is not part of your itinerary):

> Proof of accommodation for the entire stay in the Schengen area. All bookings must be made in the applicant’s name, otherwise the person who made the booking needs to produce a written statement in English (dated, signed and accompanied by PhotoID) to confirm that the applicant is covered in the bookings provided.

It's not uncommon for one person to book shared accommodations, as you did for the two of you. However, should one not be issued a visa, the other would have a problem.